# SQLserver multiple csv upload

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to upload multiple csv files to a sql server instance.

I have tried multiple things such as BCP with xp_cmdshell and some tsql scripts. However, I don’t have the permission to use cmdshell.

Is there any other way to do this ? I have access to the integration service catalogue but not the GUI and I can make a SSIS dstx file from within the import and export wizard.

Is there a way I can get the connection credentials to my local machine from the dstx file? And use this with bulk insert ? I can’t get files onto the server that SQL is running on.

Otherwise I was going use python to modify the dstx file for each csv to semi automate it. I can’t get connection credentials for the server - unless there is away I can get this from the dstx file.